# Node js Form-data as middleware

Tags: javascript, node.js, multipartform-data, multer, form-data

i am using an express nodejs server as a middleware for my application, from the frontend (react) i am building a form data and it reaches nodeJS.

In Node JS i am using multer to parse that form data, but i need to make a post request from node JS to my external server with that form-data built.

I tried to pass the multer object and also create the form-data in my nodeJS.

My Node JS code is the following:

```
 const multer = require('multer');
const upload = multer();

app.post('/api/sendFilesToServer',upload.fields([]), function (req, res) { 
const payload = req.body; 

console.log("files", payload.files[0]); 
console.log("metadata", payload.metadata); 

let formdata = new FormData(); 

//formdata.append("metadata",payload.metadata) 
formdata.append("metadata",'{"operationType":"Bulk","supportingDocuments":{"documents":[{"type":"photo","document":"Screenshot (1).png"}]}}')

formdata.append("files",payload.files[0]) 

axios({ 
method: 'POST', 
data: formdata,
url: `${url}/uploadFiles`, 
headers: headersPayload 
}).then(function (response) { 
console.log("Reponse form",req.body) 
console.log("RESPONSE") 
res.status(response.status).send(response.data); 
}).catch(function (error) { 
console.log("Reponse form ERROR",req.body) 
console.log("ERROR",error.response.data.message) 
res.status(error.response.status).send(error.response.data.message) 
});
```

I tried everything and tried to search all posts in stackoverflow, but still no clue how so solve this.

Thanks for the help,
NM

Answer (score 0):

Did u try request?
https://www.npmjs.com/package/request

```
import request from 'request'
request.post({
url: `${url}/uploadFiles`, 
headers: headersPayload,
form: formdata,
}, (err, response, body) => {

})
```

Comment: I already tried it, still no success. if i print the multer req.body, it shows me the files and exactly the structure that i need, and if i simply put that string into the request it does not work.